# Query Sales Group by week no and Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to calculate sales based on WeekNo(Yearly) and Month.

Table1: Sales

```
ID  SalDate     Amount  Region
1   2020-12-27  1000    USA
2   2020-12-28  1000    EU
3   2020-12-29  1000    AUS
4   2021-01-01  1000    USA
5   2021-01-02  1000    EU
6   2021-01-05  1000    AUS
7   2020-09-30  1000    EU
8   2020-10-01  1000    AUS

Select DateName(Month,SalDate)+' - '+Convert(Varchar(10),Year(SalDate)) Months,      
'Week '+ Convert(Varchar(50), DATEPART(WEEK, SalDate)) As Weeks,      
Sum(Amount) OrderValue      
From [Sales]
Group By DateName(Month,SalDate)+' - '+Convert(Varchar(10),Year(SalDate)),      
Convert(Varchar(50), DATEPART(WEEK, SalDate))   

Months             Weeks    Total
January - 2021     Week 1   2000.00
January - 2021     Week 2   1000.00
December - 2020    Week 53  3000.00
October - 2020     Week 40  1000.00
September - 2020   Week 40  1000.00
```

But client want to merge **Week1** Total with **Week 53**
And **Week2** show as **Week1**.
And Week 40 Merge with Sep 2020.
[image]

I want result like below

```
Months             Weeks    Total
January - 2021     Week 1   1000.00
December - 2020    Week 53  5000.00 (2000+3000)
September - 2020   Week 40  2000.00 (1000+100)
```

Kindly help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Sounds like you want `ISO_WEEK` Change `DATEPART(WEEK,...)` to `DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, ..)`

Comment: But you can't group by `months` any more . It does not make sense to do that